# Accessing a particular array element in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs

I've 2 scope element

```
 $scope.currentStatus = 1;
 $scope.availableMessage = ['zero','one','two'];
```

Is there anyway I could print out availableMessage[currentStatus] in angular?

I've tried

```
{{availableMessage[currentStatus]}} but its isn't working
{{availableMessage[0]}} doesn't work too.
```

Comment: Are there any errors in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is somewhere else; the syntax you are using is valid as you can see from this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZcZytCOVRBhjCoqhwn38?p=preview